# Initialize chart series withing foreach loop

Tags: html, vue.js, apexcharts

I am creating chart dynamically withing a `foreach` loop.

```
<v-carousel-item
      v-for="component in Platform.Components"
      :key="component"
    >
      <v-card class="d-flex flex-column" outlined>
        <v-card-title class="flex-row justify-center">{{
          component.Name
        }}</v-card-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        Failed: {{ component.UUTFailed }} Passed: {{ component.UUTPassed }}
        <div id="chart" class="align-self-center pb-2">
          <apexchart
            type="pie"
            width="350"
            :options="chartOptions"
            :series="[component.UUTFailed, component.UUTPassed]"
          ></apexchart>
        </div>
      </v-card>
    </v-carousel-item>
```

I am trying to initialize series prop with data from the iterated object but i get some weird value.
When printing the value from debug purposes it looks correct

Comment: what is the output of `{{ component.UUTFailed }}`?

Comment: It's a number. Like 17 for instance

Comment: Turn on it was fine. It was just an issue with datalabels.formatter which made me to think something is wrong